# How to set multiple div in a typical layout

Tags: css, html

For my project site front page, I have been trying to set the div's as seen in the pic below.
but I couldnt get the required result. Kindly help.

[Example Image](http://i49.tinypic.com/1pbfup.jpg)

The main div (black-border) is of 910px width.
Div-1, 2 & 5 are of same width of 900px. But Div-3 & Div-4 are different as they are content-page and side-bar. Div-3 is 635px wide and Div-4 is 255px wide.
Div-3 is further divided into sub-div's as shown in the figure above.
Height for all div's should be Auto.

How can I set the CSS & HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use floats when you have several divs next to each other horizontally (divs 3 and 4, in your case, along with all div 3 subdivs). [Here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) is a nice little tutorial that will help you a lot.

> For variable height columns, absolute positioning does not work, so let's come up with another solution.
>
> We can "float" an element to push it as far as possible to the right or to the left, and allow text to wrap around it. This is typically used for images, but we will use it for more complex layout tasks (because it's the only tool we have).

EDIT

More tutorials: http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson13.php and http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php.

You can also try experimenting with `display: inline-block;` for similar results.

Answer (score 0):

You have explained the code well, and the layout is clear. So that’s good. But what is failing? Is it DIV-3? Because that seems like an issue.  The way I would deal with that is add wrapper `<div>` elements around the multi-DIV rows of DIV-3.2, DIV-3.3 & DIV-3.4 as well as DIV-3.6 & DIV-3.7.  That way those smaller elements live in their own contained row that you can easily stack on top of each other.

If there is another issue, please edit the post or comment.

Comment: JakeGould, yes the problem is with Div-3 and all its sub-divs. First I want to set Div-3 & Div-4 as parallel. then I will try to solve the inside Divs of Div-3.

Comment: yeah Thanks. solve the Div-3 problem. but the footer div makes a problem. It comes after the div-3 and not after the right side-bar div. how to solve this? I even use a dummy div with clear:both before the footer div. but it didnt help.

Comment: I did this. but couldnt get the required result.